# AUthorization for JAX-RS always return null

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, servlet-filters, restful-authentication

Excuse me, I need some help 'bout Authorization using library Jakarta ws rs core HttpsHeader. I code for the filter function from `ContainerRequestFilter` and I want `getHeaderString` Authorization was and always return null. I give some pattern code for this case from `TokenNeededFilter.java`. I'm Using Jakarta EE 10, Tomcat 10.1, and Library Jakarta EE all. Thanks.

Slice code from `TokenNeededFilter.java`:

```java
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("url: " + requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
        
//      MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
//      for (String headerName : headers.keySet()) {
//          String headerValue = headers.getFirst(headerName);
//          System.out.println("Header : "+ headerName + " = " + headerValue);
//      }

        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        System.out.println("nilai dari authorization adalah : " + authorizationHeader);
        
        if (!isTokenBasedAuthentication(authorizationHeader)) {
            System.out.println("lewat nggga di isTOkenBasedAuthentication");
            abortWithUnauthorized(requestContext);
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("harusnya berhenti disini");
```